# why imageview take space when load multiple image in android

Tags: android, android-imageview

image take space when i load image i don;t understand what is the problem why is take space after first iamge other image is display normallly u can see my activity java class which have imagedisplay method i am alos load image here in this image is take space before and after first image

[image]

> myactivity.java

```
public void imagedisplay()
{
    itable = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.itable);

    String chekplace=null;

    Log.e("MyList Size", "Counted--->"+mylist.size());

    int size=mylist.size();
    s:
       for(int j=0;j<mylist.size();j++)
        {

            trstate = new TableRow(this);
            trstate.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);


            tstate = new TextView(this);
            tstate.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            String tempstate = mylist.get(j).get(KEY_PLACENAME).intern().toString();
            tstate.setText(tempstate);

            trstate.addView(tstate);
            itable.addView(trstate);

            chekplacename=mylist.get(j).get(KEY_PLACENAME).intern().toString();


            int counter=1;
            String nextplace=chekplacename;
            chekplace=nextplace;
            m:
                while(nextplace==chekplace)
            {
                     trimage = new TableRow(this);
             trimage.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
              for (int m = 1; m <= 4; m++)
           {                      
                       chekplace=mylist.get(j).get(KEY_PLACENAME).intern().toString();

                if(nextplace==chekplace)     
                {
                          iimage = new ImageView(this);
              iimage.setPadding(2,2,2,2);
                          BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
              bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
             bmOptions.inSampleSize = 4;
                String loadimageurl=mylist.get(j).get(KEY_PHOTOURL).intern().toString();
                counter++
                        bm = LoadImage(loadimageurl, bmOptions);

                int height=bm.getWidth();
                int width=bm.getHeight();  

               Log.e("newheight","Before--->" +height);
           Log.e("new width","Before--->"+width);
               bm=resize(bm, bm.getHeight(), bm.getWidth());
               height=bm.getWidth();
               width=bm.getHeight(); 

                    iimage.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams( height, width));
        iimage.setImageBitmap(bm);
                trimage.addView(iimage); 
                     }

           }
            itable.addView(trimage);    

        }    
     }
```

Comment: I would recommend you to use `GridView`

Comment: ya but one problem is there i have a one problem i want 4 X 2 matrix in this  add row is dynamically and 4 column is fix another problem is i have imageload from url by statename  so first display statename than related images i think which is not possible in gridview otherwise i am sure i use it